# Realtime processing of sound in Universal Apps(W 8.1/ WP 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I want to get an input from the microphone of the device and process it in realtime. I found that for capturing audio in Universal apps, I need to use [MediaCapture class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) but it seems that I can't do what I want with that class since the methods I need are done async. Is there a way to do this in C# and also, which data I can get from the stream?